# Range of k for roots of $|x^2-1|+x^2+kx=0$ lying between $(0,2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

If the equation $|x^2-1|+x^2+kx=0$ has $2$ distinct roots in $(0,2)$ then the range of $k$ is?

I tried this question as follows:
If we open the mod with -ve sign then the quadratic is converted to linear which will not have $2$ solutions, so we open the mod in +ve sign and hence it becomes $2x^2+kx-1=0$. Now I used to nature of roots concept for roots between $(0,2)$ as it is upward parabola so $f(0)>0$, $f(2)>0$ these two conditions are necessary. But $f(0)=-1<0$ is a contradiction. Can you pls tell where i went wrong or is there any other way to solve?

Comment: The two distinct roots do not necessarily come from the same quadratic, due to the modulus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Draw the graph of $ y = |x^2 - 1 | + x^2 $ on the domain $ (0, 2 )$.

> [From Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+%7Cx%5E2+-+1+%7C+%2B+x%5E2+%2C+0+%3C+x+%3C+2),
>  [image]

Now, when would this graph intersect $ y = -kx $ at 2 distinct points?

Hence, conclude that $ k \in ( - \frac{7}{2} , -1 )$.

Comment: Yes, excellent approach

Comment: @FastAndTheCurious FYI You can un-accept answers that don't make sense (esp based on issues raised in the comments).

Comment: Yes but actually i needed more of an algebraic solution to it as I won’t be able to access graphs while in exam

Comment: @FastAndTheCurious 1) You don't have to accept an answer, if none of them are "satisfactory". 2) This graph is easy to draw. You can use that to guide the algebraic proof, which is similar to Doug's approach (after fixing the issues). EG We can see that there is 1 root in (0,1) and 1 root in (1,2).

Comment: Great, Thanks Lin

Answer (score 0):

$|x^2 - 1| + x^2 + kx = kx + 1$ when $x\in [-1,1]$

If $k \ge -1$ we have one root in $(0,1]$

Now we need to find the range of $k$ such that.

$2x^2 + kx - 1$ has a root in $(1,2)$

$1 < \frac {-k + \sqrt {k^2 + 8}}{4}\\
4+k < \sqrt {k^2 + 8}\\
16 + 8k + k^2 < k^2 + 8\\
k<-1$

And

$2 > \frac {-k + \sqrt {k^2 + 8}}{4}\\
8+k > \sqrt {k^2 + 8}\\
64 + 16k + k^2 > k^2 + 8\\
16k > -56\\
k > -\frac {7}{2}$

$k\in (-\frac {7}{2},-1)$

Comment: Can you pls explain the 2nd,3rd and 4th lines

Comment: I believe that you missed the case where there are no roots in $(0,1]$ but 2 roots in $(1, 2) $ (and arguably vice versa, though that's not possible since $-kx+1$ is linear). Granted, this doesn't happen, so that doesn't change the solution set.

Comment: $|x^2 - 1| + x^2 + kx = kx + 1$, not $-kx+1$? Also in first case $x \in (-1,1)$ implies that we have one root in $(0, 1)$ if $k \leq -1$